Django does not access PostgreSQL Database using Docker
Here is the error message:
Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection failed: could not receive data from server: No route to host

Here is my .env
POSTGRES_DB=ibm_skiller
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mYP@sSw0rd
POSTGRES_USER=ibm_skiller
POSTGRES_HOST=172.19.0.2
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    env_file:
        - ./.env
    image: postgres:alpine3.19
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres16:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    #   - ./ibm_skiller_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ibm_skiller_init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ibm_skiller"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
        - skillernet


Here is the output of the docker ps command:
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                          NAMES
a2d40d97e3f0   postgres:alpine3.19   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                         postgres
f86b9bacd25e   bd43f03c087b          "./entrypoint.sh"        5 hours ago   Up 5 hours             0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp   skiller


... and how do we figure out what values Django is using to connect?

As @RichardHuxton said. Did you add the same environment to django?
